# Inconvenientes con reemplazar fragment en Adnroid Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragment

intento usar los `Fragment` en Android Studio, sin embargo me encuentro con un problema que no he logrado solucionar.

Al mostrar el siguiente `Fragment` me funciona sin fallas, solo que el `Fragment` actual no se me desaparece, queda sobre el `Fragment` que recién se mostró.

Muestro el código de los `Fragment`.

**Fragment Login XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Views.login.LoginFragment">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
      ...
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Fragment Register XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Views.login.LoginFragment">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
      ...
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Código XML de la Activity Login**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@style/loginParent"
    tools:context=".Views.login.LoginActivity">
    <ScrollView
        .....>

        <RelativeLayout
            .....>

            <LinearLayout
                ....>

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/framentLayoutLogin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:name="com.movilesii.easyshoppingapp.Views.login.LoginFragment"
                    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login"/>

            </LinearLayout>
      
        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Ahora les enseño el código JAVA del `Frament` de Login ya que quiero pasar al `Frament` de registro.

Hice el mismo reemplazo en la Activity directamente, pero me sucedió exactamente lo mismo, el `Frament` actual se sobre pone al nuevo `Frament` mostrado.

**Código Fragment JAVA**

```
package com.movilesii.easyshoppingapp.Views.login;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.movilesii.easyshoppingapp.R;
import com.movilesii.easyshoppingapp.Views.MainActivity;

public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView tvGoSignup;
    private LoginActivity myContext;

    public LoginFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        myContext = (LoginActivity) context;
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        tvGoSignup = view.findViewById(R.id.tvGoSignup);
        tvGoSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.tvGoSignup:
                changeFragment();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    private void changeFragment(){
        RegisterFragment registerFragment = new RegisterFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.framentLayoutLogin, registerFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Esta es la salida que muestra la aplicación.

[image: Carga el fragment por defecto, el de Login]

[image: Carga el siguiente Fragment pero no oculta el anterior]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> solo que el Fragment actual no se me desaparece, queda sobre el
> Fragment que recién se mostró.

El problema es que tienes inicialmente en tu layout `fragment_login.xml` un Fragment,

```
          ...
          ...
           <fragment
            android:id="@+id/framentLayoutLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.movilesii.easyshoppingapp.Views.login.LoginFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login"/>
            ...
            ...
```

si deseas realizar un "reemplazo" de un `Fragment`, solo podràs reemplazar un Fragment agregado dinámicamente". Para esto usa un `FrameLayout`

```
...
...
<FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/framentLayoutLogin"
    ...
    ...
   />
...
...
```

Tu còdigo ya esta realizando la transacciòn de `RegisterFragment`:

```
private void changeFragment(){
        RegisterFragment registerFragment = new RegisterFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.framentLayoutLogin, registerFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, en realidad me funcionó. Llevaba toda la tarde buscando en Foros, videos, etc y no encontraba como solucionar. Lo hice como me dijiste, insertando de manera dinámica el Fragment desde el código Java y Luego lo reemplacé y ahora si me funciona perfecto. Mil Gracias.