# Llamar fragment desde un recyclerview con evento onclickListener

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, onclick

Tengo el siguiente codigo para llamar un fragment desde un recyclerview dentro de otro fragment actualmente mi codigo no me esta presentando falla como tal pero cuando presiono el boton ver detalles en ves de mandarme a otro fragment me esta sobre poniendo el fragment en el mismo recycler view anexo imagen de la falla ya revise el codigo y lo intente con switch's
y no me funciona me pueden auxiliar para saber a que se debe esto

Imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con la siguiente clase lleno mi recycler view con datos almaecenados en mi base de datos en el servidor.

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>,Response.ErrorListener{

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    Usuario usuario;
    RampasAdapter adaptador;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    RecyclerView recyclerUsuarios;
    ArrayList<Usuario> listaUsuarios;

    ProgressDialog progress;

    // RequestQueue request;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vista=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        listaUsuarios=new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerUsuarios= (RecyclerView) vista.findViewById(R.id.idRecycler);
        recyclerUsuarios.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
        recyclerUsuarios.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // request= Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        cargarWebService();

        return vista;

    }
    private void cargarWebService() {

        progress=new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progress.setMessage("Consultando...");

        String ip=getString(R.string.ip);

        String url=ip+"/ejemploBDRemota/wsJSONConsultarLista.php";

        jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
        // request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        VolleySingleton.getIntanciaVolley(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se puede conectar "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println();
        Log.d("ERROR: ", error.toString());
        progress.hide();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Usuario usuario=null;

        JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray("usuario");

        try {

            for (int i=0;i<json.length();i++){
                usuario=new Usuario();
                JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                jsonObject=json.getJSONObject(i);


                usuario.setRampa(jsonObject.optString("rampa"));
                usuario.setCaja(jsonObject.optString("trailer"));
                usuario.setDestino(jsonObject.optString("plant_code"));
                usuario.setAccion(jsonObject.optString("action"));
                usuario.setTipo(jsonObject.optString("type_material"));
                usuario.setSalida(jsonObject.optString("prog_date"));
                listaUsuarios.add(usuario);
            }
            progress.hide();
            RampasAdapter adapter=new RampasAdapter(listaUsuarios);
            recyclerUsuarios.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se ha podido establecer conexión con el servidor" +
                    " "+response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progress.hide();
        }

    }
    
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

Adapter.java

```
public class RampasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RampasAdapter.UsuariosHolder>{

    List<Usuario> listaUsuario;
    Context context;

    public RampasAdapter(List<Usuario> listaUsuario) {
        this.listaUsuario = listaUsuario;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public UsuariosHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View vista= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.embarques_list,parent,false);
        return new UsuariosHolder(vista);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UsuariosHolder holder,  @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int i) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();

        String fecha = dateFormat.format(date);

        holder.txRampa.setText(listaUsuario.get(i).getRampa());
        holder.txCaja.setText(listaUsuario.get(i).getCaja());
        holder.txDest.setText(listaUsuario.get(i).getDestino());
        holder.txSal.setText(listaUsuario.get(i).getSalida());

        // set events
        holder.btnDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
                GalleryFragment fragment = new GalleryFragment();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main,
                        fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaUsuario.size();
    }

    public class UsuariosHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        //textview
        TextView txRampa,txCaja,txDest,txAccion,txTipo,txSal,txState;

        //cardview
        CardView cvTarjeta;

        //buttons
        Button btnDetails,btnEditHeader;

        public UsuariosHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            context = itemView.getContext();

            txRampa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRampa);
            cvTarjeta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvTarjeta);
            txCaja= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCaja);
            txDest= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDestino);
            txSal= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSalida);

            btnDetails= (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDetalles);
            btnEditHeader= (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnEditHeader);

        }
    }

    public void filtrar(ArrayList<Usuario> filtroUsuarios) {
        this.listaUsuario = filtroUsuarios;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Si me pudieran ayudar a saber por que pasa esto se los agradeceria

`Anexo el codigo xml de mis layout`

Fragment_home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment" >
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="19dp" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/idRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/count" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment_gallery

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.gallery.GalleryFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Pruebas SetOnClickListener"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

El archivo content_main tenia un `<fragment>`, lo cambie por `<FrameLayout>` pero la aplicacion ya no abrio solo abre y se cierra en automatico.

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,IFragments{

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    TextView welcomeusers;

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Fragment miFragment=null;
        boolean fragmentSeleccionado=false;

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            miFragment=new HomeFragment();
            fragmentSeleccionado=true;
        }

        if (fragmentSeleccionado==true){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main,miFragment).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Cuando reemplaces el fragmento no lo agregués al "backstack" (`.addToBackStack(null)`), simplemente realiza el reemplazo siempre, esto para que no se sobreponga

```
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, fragment).commit();
```

---

Si continúas teniendo el problema, entonces seguramente tienes en tu layout definido un `Fragment`, **solo podrás reemplazar un `Fragment` agregado dinámicamente, usando un `FrameLayout`**.

revisa: [**Inconvenientes con reemplazar fragment en Android**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/488257/95)

Comment: Aun se sigue sobreponiendo no cambia

Comment: La otra razòn es que tengas en el layout definido un Fragment, revisa la actualizaciòn de la respuesta.

Comment: No cuento con fragments ya actualice mi pregunta y agregue los xml de mi layout ninguno es fragment solo las clases sinceramente si no se que este haciendo mal

Comment: Encontre un `fragment` en el `content_main` y lo cambie por un `framelayout` pero la aplicacion ya no abrio

Comment: Entonces posiblemente este es el problema. Ahora, si tienes un error, es muy importante revisar el LogCat para obtener que sucede.

Comment: Ya añadi el error que me arroja el logcat me dice que no encuentra el NavController del MainActivity